# How to refactor private method with code in subclass into abstract method in superclass (Eclipse IDE)?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have a private method with code in subclass A. I need to refactor so that this method becomes protected abstract method in superclass and subclass implements this method with the code I now have in this subclass A.

I do not see any relevant menu item in Eclipse.

Pull Up moves code to super class. Neither Alt+Shift+T, nor Refactor in main menu do any help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste the method into a protected abstract method in your superclass. Or try selecting, then right-click->Refactor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an immediate way to accomplish this with Eclipse (Neon, I'm using). The most approximate would be selecting your private method, then `Refactor > Pull up > Set action=declare abstract in destination`. But this forces Eclipse to **create** a new superclass, not to use an existing superclass.